# NginX in docker 2nd domain return 502 bad gateway

Tags: docker, nginx

I have 2 domains pointing to one virtual private server ubuntu 21. The first domain(running on port 3000) works as expected, the second domain(running on port 4000 on container and 5000 on host) does not and return nginx 502 bad gateway. I have added port 4000 point to 80 on nginx container:

[image]

I have configured like below:

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    ports:
      - "3000:80" # nginx listen on 80
      - "4000:80"
    volumes:
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf:ro

  pwm-node:
    build: .
    image: my_acc/pwm-node
    environment:
      - PORT=3000
    depends_on:
      - mongo

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes:
      - mongo-db:/data/db

  redis:
    image: redis
volumes:
  mongo-db:
```

nginx conf:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name first_domain.com www.first_domain.com;

    # Redirect http to https
    location / {
        return 301 https://first_domain.com$request_uri;
    }
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name second_domain.com www.second_domain.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:4000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name first_domain.com www.first_domain.com;

    ssl on;
    server_tokens off;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/first_domain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/first_domain.com/privkey.pem;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/dhparam/dhparam-2048.pem;

    ssl_buffer_size 8k;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+3DES:!ADH:!AECDH:!MD5;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass http://pwm-node:3000;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like nginx does not accept `http://localhost:4000;`. I may have to add node-app-4000 to docker-compose.yml as a service and replace localhost with node-app-4000

Comment: Are you trying to establish a connection on Grafana?
If yes then try to use  " host.docker.internal:5000 "  to see if the connection will be established. Please let me know about the outcome

Comment: no! I just want to add 2 domains to 1 ip. The answer above works 2 domains are now being served their own content. 

However it's weird that 2 nodejs apps that are responsible now all can be accessed with port 3000 and 4000 and when docker ps it shows only 4000?